# How to resume and upload file upload using tus-client

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

i want to `pause` and `resume` file upload as shown in this example https://tus.io/demo.html

i'm using this https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client **Plugin**

i searched for every where but did not find any solution

**Question:** i want to `pause` and `resume` `fileupload` for **multiple** file

**here is my full code:** https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/dwXEMM?editors=1010

Please help me thanks in advance!!

Comment: the only thing i don't know how to 1. stop upload 2. resume upload with multiple Files

Answer (score 4):

### Uppy

You can use Uppy File Uploader for resumable uploads. It wraps tus-js-client.js and provide a simplified interface.

You can find its documentation [here](https://uppy.io/docs/tus/) and live example [here](https://uppy.io/examples/dashboard/)

After importing Uppy JS and CSS files on your web page you need to do some scripting something similar to following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var uppy = new Uppy.Core({ debug: true, autoProceed: false });
  uppy.use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
    trigger: '.UppyModalOpenerBtn',
    inline: true,
    target: '.DashboardContainer'
});
  uppy.use(Uppy.Tus10, { endpoint: 'http://localhost:1080/files/' });
  uppy.run();
</script>
```

Some HTML:

```
<div class="DashboardContainer"></div>
```

Hope this would help. If not, feel free to further discuss the issue.

### TUS protocol <sup>(Edit)</sup>

As discussed in comments, you want to upload multiple files using`tus-client-js` instead of Uppy.
For that you can have a look at this post to handle multiple uploads scenario:
https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client/issues/115

The post is about initiating another file upload after the first one is completed successfully.

**EDIT**

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client#basic-usage) of `tus-js-client` library, you need to call `abort` to pause and `start` method of your file upload object to pause/resume the upload:

> 3. Optionally pause the upload if the user/application wishes to do so using Upload#abort. This will cause any currently running transfers to be immediately stopped.
> 4. Optionally resume the previously paused upload by called Upload#start again. This will resume the upload at the point at which
>    it had stopped before. You can also use this approach to continue the
>    upload after an error has occurred.

To learn more about what is going on under the hood, please visit this [link](https://tus.io/protocols/resumable-upload.html#how-are-pauseresume-handled-when-should-i-delete-partial-uploads).

Comment: But **Stop** and **resume** option is there in `tus-client-js`, it is shown in demo https://tus.io/demo.html. can't i use the same

Comment: Agree. Stop and resume options are available in `tus-client-js`. The fact is, Uppy is built on top of `tus-client-js`. `tus-client-js` is just a JavaScript library without styling of-course. But Uppy is full-featured file uploader for Web browsers and supports tus. In other words, if you go with `tus-client-js` then you need to cater progress styling yourself.

Comment: Then what are the specific issues you are facing? Because the code you shared has no errors at all.

Comment: the only thing i don't know how to `1. stop upload 2. resume upload` with multiple Files

Comment: hmmm. Uppy already supports multiple files :) But have to check if and how is it possible with `tus-client-js`. I think it would be a manual solution/workaround that you have to implement using `tus-client-js` and keep track of multiple files. If there isn't any critical requirement of not using Uppy then I would suggest one should go with Uppy.

Comment: I've just updated the answer to accommodate multiple files upload scenario. It's kind of a workaround though.

Comment: My posted code works for multiple files.  Only I Don't know `stop` and `resume`

Comment: @skBangalore, I've updated the answer, hope this would help.

Comment: I have red same documentation but don't  know how to implement  on  **ongoing**  `file object`.  If you help me with that then it will be real help.  Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: To further assist you, can you please update the code because the code you mentioned is at very basic level. It doesn't show how you handled multiple files, and how you are planning to give stop/resume functionality.